# Will the css properties 'left' or 'right' affect other elements on a webpage

Tags: html, css

The title is fairly self explanatory. Additional details to consider are...

The element i'm applying the css to will be `position:relative`

The element will be embedded onto a web page

I'm using `left: -9999px` to move the element off screen temporarily

The element may or may not move 'over' or 'through' other elements on the page.

Will doing this have any negative effects such as altering the layout/placement of other elements on the page?

Thanks

Comment: Why `position:relative`? Wouldn't `absolute` be more logical? Or this - http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/

Comment: Try it out and see what happens: http://jsfiddle.net/k3yLP/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, offsetting a relatively-positioned element will not affect the layout of other elements in the same flow, because other elements will only respect the "original" position of the element (i.e. the position if it had not been offset). The offset properties only create a visual effect on the element being offset. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#relative-positioning):

> Once a box has been laid out according to the normal flow or floated, it may be shifted relative to this position. This is called *relative positioning*. Offsetting a box (B1) in this way has no effect on the box (B2) that follows: B2 is given a position as if B1 were not offset and B2 is not re-positioned after B1's offset is applied. This implies that relative positioning may cause boxes to overlap.

However, the spec does point out an edge case (immediately after the above portion):

> ... However, if relative positioning causes an 'overflow:auto' or 'overflow:scroll' box to have overflow, the UA must allow the user to access this content (at its offset position), which, through the creation of scrollbars, may affect layout.

For example, scrollbars can reduce the width of a container and cause other elements to wrap where they otherwise would not.

Answer (score 0):

No.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> **relative**
>
> This keyword lays out all elements as though the element were not positioned, and then adjust the element's position, **without changing layout** (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have been had it not been positioned). The effect of position:relative on table-*-group, table-row, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

As you can see in this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yqeJX/), the `relative`ly positioned element simply overlaps other elements, without affecting the original layout - the other elements stays as it was previously (other than the fact that currently it's overlapped, *obviously*).